# Depending on which parameters can config binding WCF

Tags: wcf

what is config The best For binding WCF in terms of closetimeout, buffer , send Time out and etc .the other words .Depending on which parameters can config binding WCF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is kind of hard to understand. There is not a given "best" binding configuration for all wcf services (in that case it would be the only one) - it all depends on your application and the requirements on your application!

Here are two good starting links on msdn:

(1) [System.ServiceModel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(http%3A%2F%2Fschemas.microsoft.com%2F.NetConfiguration%2Fv2.0%23configuration%2Fsystem.serviceModel%2Fbindings);k(http%3A%2F%2Fschemas.microsoft.com%2F.NetConfiguration%2Fv2.0%23bindings);k(http%3A%2F%2Fschemas.microsoft.com%2F.NetConfiguration%2Fv2.0%23configuration%2Fsystem.serviceModel);k(http%3A%2F%2Fschemas.microsoft.com%2F.NetConfiguration%2Fv2.0%23system.serviceModel);k(vs.xmleditor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5)&rd=true)

(2) [Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731399(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you want speed I would go for netTcpBinding if it should serve over Internet if you don't need that named pipes could be an option.

Request / min? Depends on what your service does? But the architecture/binding will definitely server more then 200 request/min. See this blog post:
http://blog.shutupandcode.net/?p=1085

Comment: i want to understand do exist Pattern For Solution.for example for <200 request per/min use from pattern X binding.